# API authorization 401 problem (only JS via browsers) - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, http-status-code-401, yandex-api

I need to get (any) OK-response from Yandex SpeechKit.API.
I got API-KEY (valid) and successfully used it and received responses via NodeJS and even GitBash (see links to screens below).
But browsers show me 401:
[image]
There're rules for API requests: [docs](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/speechkit/tts/request).
My JS code for browsers:

```js
let api_key = '*********c_Ujs9scAhJVVZOs2xjnbvevqj6OFFm';
let params = new URLSearchParams();

const text = 'Привет!';
params.append('text', text);
params.append('voice', 'jane');
params.append('emotion', 'good');
params.append('lang', 'ru-RU');
params.append('speed', '1.0');
params.append('format', 'oggopus');

const fetchButton = document.getElementById("fetchButton");

fetchButton.onclick = () => {

  fetch('https://tts.api.cloud.yandex.net/speech/v1/tts:synthesize', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: params,
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
      //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Api-Key ' + api_key,
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(`!!! + ${err} + !!!!!!!!`)
  });

}
```

There're code examples for Node and Bash:

[image: [nodeJS code][3]]
[image: gitBash code]

Comment: Hmm, the [documentation](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/speechkit/concepts/auth) seems to suggest that the Authorization header should start `Bearer`

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ```
> mode: "no-cors",            //required
> ```

… this means "I am making a cross-origin request, but I am not doing anything that requires the server grant me permission with CORS so instead of throwing errors, fail silently".

You also said:

> ```
> 'Authorization': 'Api-Key ' + api_key,
> ```

Setting this header requires permission from CORS. Since you are in no-cors mode it automatically and silently fails to be set.

Since you didn't set the authorisation key, you get a *401 Unauthorised* response from the server.

---

You can't use no-cors mode here, even if you have a comment saying it is required.

There is some [further reading on CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068) you may find useful. Note that since the service you are using requires an API key and imposes limits, it likely isn't intended for use from a browser and you should implement a server-side solution instead.

Comment: thanks a lot. How do you think, if i upload my NodeJs file (which is successfully working with) to Heroku (for example) and will request to it from browser, will it work?